# Index was out of bounds exception in splitting string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have written this code for splitting string

```
 protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string oldstr = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    string[] exp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(oldstr, "-");
    int int1 = Convert.ToInt32(exp[0]);
    int int2 = Convert.ToInt32(exp[1]);
}
```

it is giving me exception

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

at the line `int int2 = Convert.ToInt32(exp[1]);`

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1-2">1-2 years</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3-4 ">3-4 years</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5-7">5-7 years</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Did you debug it? What value can you see in "exp" on the same line when you put a break point there?

Comment: which means that `exp` doesn't have the second element. Check `exp.Length`

Comment: And what does an empty <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem> doing there inside your dropdownlist?

Answer (score 4):

Update you mark up like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <asp:ListItem Value="0-0"></asp:ListItem> // add 0 and 0
        <asp:ListItem Value="1-2">1-2 years</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3-4">3-4 years</asp:ListItem>//remove space after 4 
        <asp:ListItem Value="5-7">5-7 years</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Rather than convert make use of TryParse like as below and also check the length of splitted array

```
//string[] exp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(oldstr, "-");
//use string split rathre than using regular expression because character split is 
// faster than regular expression split
string[] exp = oldstr.Split('-');
if(exp.Length>0)
{
  int int1;
  if(int.TryParse(exp[0], out num1))
 { // further code }
  int int2;
 if(int.TryParse(exp[1], out num1))
 { // further code }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` of first element of `DropDownList` is empty string and as you bind the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired for first element and splitting it will give you array of zero elements. Apply condition on index before you access array by index.

```
int int1 = 0;
if(exp.Length > 0)
     int1 = Convert.ToInt32(exp[0]);

int int2 = 0;
if(exp.Length > 1)
     int2 = Convert.ToInt32(exp[1]);
```

Alternatively add value for the first element, like 0-1 year

```
<asp:ListItem Value="0-1">Upto one one year</asp:ListItem>
```